# Retrieve ID of a web control if it satisfies a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="buses" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="bus1" runat="server" CssClass="Bangalore Mumbai Delhi"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="bus2" runat="server" CssClass="Bangalore Kolkata Delhi Chennai"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="bus3" runat="server" CssClass="Chennai Mumbai Kolkata"></asp:Panel>

</asp:Panel>
```

What I want to do is specify an if-condition and if a panel inside "buses" satisfies the condition, its ID should be retrieved.

For example, if the CssClass property of "bus1" contains "Bangalore", then its ID i.e. "bus1" should be retrieved.

Please note: The conditions should be checked for the panels inside "buses" only.

What code should I use in the .aspx.cs file to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
string[] selectedId = buses.Controls
            .OfType<Panel>()
            .Where(p => p.CssClass.Contains("Bangalore"))
            .Select(p => p.ID)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. But this only shows "bus1". "bus2" contains "Bangalore" too. How do I get "bus2" to show up too??

Comment: @ClementStanley You're right, I've corrected the answer